# How to do clear data of application programmatically on updating of the application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to clear the application data of my application when updated. What do I want to do for this?. I want to clear my previously build application data on updation programmatically. I had tried some code but it doesn't work for me.

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

UpdateReciever

```
public class UpdateReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("pm clear " + context.getPackageName() + " HERE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }/**/

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? `UpdateReciever` is not triggered or `pm clear` doesn't clear?

Comment: update receiever is not triggerd@eleven

Comment: It would be better to start service, in onReceive, which does all this work.

Comment: How to do this ??@ArtemBotnev

Comment: Remove the `<data>` element from that `<intent-filter>`. There's not going to be any data on that broadcast `Intent`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me @MikeM.

Comment: Your Receiver should be running now. I don't know about that `pm` command. Why don't you just clear everything "properly"? Deleting files, using `clear()` for `SharedPreferences`, etc.

Comment: I had used Bunch of shared preferences.@MikeM.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MikeM. Now it is being working thanks for your consideration.